# How to remove duplicates and print only those lines that contain a string and has the highest value in a specific column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

For example in the below example

I want to remove the duplicate ids from the second column and print only those ids that have the highest value in the third column

```
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -   
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core  
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11  
MS0736357 PT01000010.1.8 0.062 18.2 0.5 (Saprolegnia  
MS0260587 PT01000010.1.2 0.5 15.4 0.1 VII-activating  
MS0402367 PT01000010.1.2 0.6 15.1 0.1 V-activating  
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus  
MS0438713 PT01000010.1.3 0.2 18.1 0 TRP3  
MS0436466 PT01000010.1.3 0.48 17 0 -  
MS0436647 PT01000010.1.3 0.49 16.9 0 Stomatobaculum  
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase  
MS0436602 PT01000010.1.3 0.55 16.8 0 Desulfosporosinus
```

Output should be

```
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core  
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11  
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus  
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase
```

Comment: @Annotator: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

A fairly KISS approach that avoids sorting would be to process the file twice, the first time to find the maximum values of each second column key, and the second to print the lines that contain those values:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{x[$2] = $3+0 > x[$2] ? $3 : x[$2]; next} $3 == x[$2] {print}' file file
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase
```

As it stands, this will print all instances that tie for each maximum - you could add a `!seen[$2]++` condition to limit it to the first occurrence.

Comment: $3+0? padding of sort?

Comment: @bac0n `+0` forces numeric conversion - just in case `$3` contains non-numeric data anywhere

Comment: if i understod you right `... {if (!seen[x[$2]]++) print} file file`

Comment: @bac0n yup that should do it - or perhaps more idiomatically `$3 == x[$2] && !seen[$2]++ {print}` making use of short-circuit evaluation (`{print}` being optional since it's the default action)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```sh
$ sort -gt' ' -k3,3r foo.txt | awk '!seen[$2]++' | sort -t' ' -k2
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -   
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core  
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus  
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase  
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I need the same output but with little modification if possible.. I want to preserve their original order (PT01000001.1.1, PT01000007.1.1, PT01000010.1.8,  PT01000010.1.2, PT01000010.1.3) in the output resultant file instead of sorting them from lower to higher values (PT01000001.1.1, PT01000007.1.1,....PT01000010.1.8)  . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `sort` like so:

```
sort -uk2,2 <(sort -k3,3rn FileName)
```

Change **`FileName`** to the name of **your file** and run the command from within the same directory containing your file.

**output:**

```
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -   
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core  
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus  
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase  
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11
```

---

To preserve **original order**, however, you can use `grep` with `sort` like so:

```
grep "$(sort -k3,3rn FileName | sort -uk2,2)" FileName
```

Change **both occurrences** of **`FileName`** to the name of **your file** and run the command from within the same directory containing your file.

**output:**

```
MS1199089 PT01000001.1.1 0.63 16.4 0.7 -
MS0068379 PT01000007.1.1 0.96 13.9 0.4 core
MS0950857 PT01000010.1.8 0.1 17.5 0.2 S11
MS0416158 PT01000010.1.2 0.65 15 0.1 Callorhinchus
MS0438816 PT01000010.1.3 0.59 16.7 0 peptidase
```

---

To **save the output** of either commands above to a **file**, add `> SaveOutput.txt` after them like so:

```
sort -uk2,2 <(sort -k3,3rn FileName) > SaveOutput.txt
```

and

```
grep "$(sort -k3,3rn FileName | sort -uk2,2)" FileName > SaveOutput.txt
```

The output will be saved to a file named `SaveOutput.txt` in the same directory.

Please see [`man sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/sort.1.html) and [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/grep.1.html) for extra information.

Please also have a look at what [LC_ALL=C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do) does and why you might need it. Thank you to **@bac0n** for bringing it up in [the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316571/how-to-remove-duplicates-and-print-only-those-lines-that-contain-a-string-and-ha/1316693#comment2241882_1316693).

Comment: don't seem to sort right.

Comment: @bac0n You mean it sorts wrong, how?

Comment: sort -V -uk2,2 <(sort -V -k2,2 -k3,3r data), don't think -n sort fracttion ... but I'm not sure

Comment: @bac0n I had that thought at first then changed it (no need to sort k2 twice)  see the edit history in my answer, the output is the same. But why `-V`?

Comment: sorry version sort ... handles float

Comment: @bac0n I know, it is in the linked manual in my answer but unneeded in this case. Try and see  `sort -uk2,2 <(sort -k3,3rn FileName)`. k2 is not pure version numbers.

Comment: ah... it's a Locale thing, tried LC_ALL=C

Comment: @bac0n I took a took at your profile *Sweden* .... now I understand why :) I do not know for sure but if your locale is set to Sweden ....Yes in this case maybe. Appreciate your feedback always :)